# Перенаправление io потоков внешних команд по кругу

Tags: python, linux, bash, pipes

Есть две программы. Скомпилированы, работают, редактировать нельзя. Сначала запускается первая программа.

1. Первая программа выводит строку через свой stdout.
2. Эту строку надо ввести в stdin второй программы.
3. Вторая программа выводит другую строку через stdout.
4. Эту строку надо ввести в stdin первой программы.

Потом всё это повторится несколько раз. Первой завершается вторая программа. Если вручную копировать вывод этих программ, то всё работает. Но надо весь этот процесс автоматизировать и составить лог. Желательно stderr обоих программ тоже добавить в лог. Как это сделать?

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Circle Piping to and from 2 Python Subprocesses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39232164/4279)

Comment: Не работает. Там каждый раз заново процесс запускают, а здесь нужно 1 раз каждый запустить пока не завершатся копировать их вывод. А после вызова communicate процесс закрывается. Даже лог составить нельзя т.к. если при запуске процесса его вывод направить на ввод другого процесса, то communicate вернёт None вместо stdout.

Comment: Посмотрите [на второй ответ с большой картинкой змеи](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40317512/4279), который запускает только 1 раз две команды и не использует `.communicate()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

«закольцевать» две программы можно, используя «[именованный канал (pipeline)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB#.D0.98.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.BB.D1.8B_.D0.B2_Unix)».

1. создайте в текущем каталоге такой *pipeline* с произвольным именем (в примере — `канал`):

   ```
   $ mkfifo канал
   ```

   можете убедиться, что это не «рядовой» файл/каталог, по первой букве в выводе `ls -l`:

   ```
   $ ls -l канал
   prw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Nov  2 21:31 канал
   ```
2. запустите связку из ваших двух программ (`программа1` и `программа2`):

   ```
   $ программа1 <канал | программа2 >канал
   ```

первая программа будет читать из *stdin*, для которого назначен *pipeline* по имени `канал`, а выводить в *stdout*, который перенаправляем (с помощью `|`) в *stdin* второй программы, *stdout* которой, в свою очередь, «заворачиваем обратно» в *pipeline* по имени `канал`.

а чтобы посмотреть, что же там «творится», в их *stdout*-ах, можно воспользоваться программой `tee`, вставив её в разрывы:

```
$ программа1 <канал | tee -a лог1 | программа2 | tee -a лог2 >канал
```

в файл `лог1` попадёт всё, что `программа1` выдаст в *stdout*, а в файл `лог2` попадёт всё, что в свой *stdout* запишет `программа2`.

а *stderr* программ, раз его не надо никуда передавать, можно сохранять в файл конструкцией `2>>файл`:

```
$ программа1 <канал 2>>лог.stderr1 | tee -a лог1 | программа2 2>>лог.stderr2 | tee -a лог2 >канал
```

---

небольшая иллюстрация (используется одна программа на языке shell, но запущенная с разными аргументами):

```
$ cat программа
#!/bin/bash    
arg=$1
echo ${arg}0
i=1
while read n; do [ $i -eq 4 ] && break; echo ${n}${arg}${i}; ((i++)); done
```

запуск:

```
$ ./программа а <канал | tee -a лог1 | ./программа б | tee -a лог2 >канал
```

вот что попало в логи:

```
$ cat лог1
а0
б0а1
а0б1а2
б0а1б2а3
$ cat лог2
б0
а0б1
б0а1б2
а0б1а2б3
```

Comment: Хороший ответ. Стоит упомянуть возможные проблемы с буферами ввода/вывода из-за перенаправления в pipe вместо tty (к примеру, если команда  grep, то возможно `--line-buffered` параметр нужно передать).

Comment: Работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @jfs, вероятно, вы знаете о проблемах с буферами ввода/вывода гораздо больше меня. если вы считаете появление таких проблем в данном случае вероятным, а наличие обработки — существенным, то, я думаю, вам стоит написать собственный вариант ответа.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: если для автора работает, то хорошо, так как универсального решения для проблемы с внутренними буферами не существует (каждая программа может как угодно свои внутренние буфера ввода/вывода организовывать). Я уже ответил на похожий вопрос и улучшил ответ с помощью вашей `fifo` идеи (там где это работает). Чтобы увидеть проблему с буферами, сотрите  [`setvbuf()` вызов во внешней программе (аналог `--line-buffered` опции)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40317512/4279).