# Как взаимодействовать с dzen2 и есть ли обратная связь с работающим shell процессом?

Tags: linux, shell, archlinux

Здравствуйте. Я хочу создать крупное интерактивное меню на dzen2. Запускаю script.sh | dzen2. Далее полный пример: нажимаю на активную зону в dzen. dzen запускает Thunar(например). Иконка thunar в dzen меняет цвет. Когда я закрываю thunar - иконка меняется снова. Ну и собственно главная проблема в том, как мне получить изменения в работающий script.sh. Скрипт на питоне я планировал решать с помощью сокетов. Как поступить в bash - не знаю, но видел проекты где панель dzen была интерактивной. Может линуксоиды знаю как реализуются такие фичи средствами самого dzen или хотя бы подскажут как снаружи взаимодействовать с крутящимся в цикле shell скриптом?

Comment: *Может линуксоиды знаю как реализуются такие фичи средствами самого dzen* — это тайное знание, доступное лишь в [священных скрижалях](https://github.com/robm/dzen). посвящённые в него обязаны хранить обет молчания. // по поводу передачи информации: через трубу (pipe) информация передаётся только в одну сторону. так что скрипту самому придётся узнавать то же самое (и, вероятно, теми же средствами), что и программе dzen.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я внимательно читал главную страницу. Если я что-то не понял на счёт обратного взаимодействия в dzen, пожалуйста, подскажите в явном виде как вернуть какое-либо значение через ^ca(). И ещё, на счёт взаимодействия с процессом, я не о пайпе. Предположим есть независимо запущенный скрипт с циклом. Как достучаться до него извне? Юникс сокеты в шелл - самый простой вариант? Промежуточный лог файл который постоянно считывается циклом на предмет изменения - по моему не очень красивый вариант.

Comment: [пример использования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/586100/178576) именованной трубы (*named pipe*) в скрипте оболочки.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin спасибо, отличный метод взаимодействия.